# Dynamically Change listview size with the data binded inside winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, resize

I have a problem with listview in Winforms.The scenario is like i have a list view inside a winform and usually data would be binded with count 5-10 items.So requirement is like i have to change the winform size according to the data binded in the listview.

Say for example- 2 items were binded,winform size should decrease .The Maximum items that would be binded will be 15.I already set  winform size according to it.So decrease in winform size would be the only condition to be taken care of.

Any help would be well appreciated.

-Renji

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxItems = 15;
Size maxSize = new Size(150, 150); //Your default maxSize on 15 items

void changeSizeAccordingToItems(ListView listview)
{
     int currentItems = listview.Count;
     int newFormWidth = (maxSize.Width / maxItems) * currentItems;
     int newFormHieght = (maxSize.Height / maxItems) * currentItems;
     this.Size = new Size(newFormWidth, newFormHeight);
}
```